# How can I use PonyORM to query to relational database using RASA chatbot?

Tags: rasa-core, rasa, ponyorm

I am building a chatbot in RASA which will query to relational database, i came across PonyORM is there a way i can use PonyORM to map my RASA entities  and Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Rasa you'll setup an [action server](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/actions/#) to handle any API calls or database queries. You can build your own version of the [rasa-sdk](https://hub.docker.com/r/rasa/rasa-sdk) docker image which is described in the rasa-sdk [git repo](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-sdk)